# Correct word for a little toy that always stands up?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, translation, image-identification

In Spanish, we have a word for a little toy that always stand up, "tentetieso".

I want to search for those toys in English, but I can't find the correct word or specific description to find them.

[image: image of a children's toy, a clown, that cannot be knocked down]

Comment: Step one: go to the Wikipedia article on tentetieso. Step two: select English from the language list. [Done](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roly-poly_toy).

Comment: By the title, I was expecting a [push puppet](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=push+puppet&t=ffab&iax=images&ia=images).

Comment: The more general descriptive term for an object that always "stands up" by itself is *self-righting*.

Comment: it doesn't always stand up

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'd call that a [Weeble Wobble or Weeble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weeble) but I think that's a trademark usage of a roly-poly toy (as GileBrt notes as the generic term for one) much like *Hoover* is not only used for *vacuum cleaners* that are made by *Hoover* but other manufacturers too. Whether this is a UK convention though I'm unsure [Judging from comments it's AmE too].

I'm also certain that somewhere I've seen a cartoon or kids TV character roly-poly toy that even says "Weeble Wobble" as it bobs back and forth. (Also [Weebl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weebl_and_Bob))

Comment: Wasn't there a TV ad that said "Weebles wobble but they don't fall down"? Yes, found it :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKcAWO_IznI Happy memories :))

Comment: Weeble Wobble is the name in AmE as well.

Comment: Before reading this I would have understood "weeble" but not "roly-poly toy", FWIW. (I'm British.)

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Likewise, as an American.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime Same here as a fairly Commonwealth-contaminated American.  Never heard of the other,  just weebles.

Comment: Unless this has been genericised, the answer is off-topic on ELU.

Answer (score 18):

I believe it is called a [roly-poly toy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roly-poly_toy). :)

> Wikipedia
>
> A **roly-poly toy**, *round-bottomed doll*, *tilting doll*, *tumbler* or *wobbly man* is a round-bottomed toy, usually egg-shaped, that tends to right itself when pushed at an angle, and does this in seeming contradiction to the force of gravity.

Comment: Yep, we called this a "rolly-polly doll" when I was a kid.

Comment: I don't dispute that this is the "official" name but I (like the commenters [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/506883/63503)) have only ever heard of these things called weebles. If somebody said "roly-poly toy" to me, I wouldn't actually know what they meant, and they'd have to explain it.

Comment: This name is curious given that a [roly poly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roll_(gymnastics)#Forward_Roll) specfically involves turning all the way over. So, they're called roly poly toys because they... don't do roly polys?

Comment: If you told me you had a roly-poly doll, I would be very confused and wonder why you had a plush [pill bug](https://www.google.com/search?biw=2560&bih=1477&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=7wtDXbqYG8zm5gLU3q_YCg&q=roly+poly&oq=roly+poly&gs_l=img.3..35i39l2j0i67j0l5j0i67j0.3438.3558..3687...0.0..0.67.124.2......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i10j0i7i30.N33e-5COouE&ved=0ahUKEwj6y_nmhOLjAhVMs1kKHVTvC6sQ4dUDCAY&uact=5) (northern US here).

Comment: @AakashM A gymnast doing a proper roll doesn't fall down, they land back on their feet. So while the weeble doesn't roll all the way over, it still lands on its feet when it starts to roll. I admit it's a stretch, but language doesn't have to be logical. "poly" is probably in both just because it rhymes, they're not references to each other.

Answer (score -1):

It is Okiagari-koboshi or daruma doll

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: These don't appear to be English language terms for the toy.

Comment: Looking these up, they are used for specific Japanese toys that are made of papier-mâché. In my experience, these terms would not be used in an English speaking country for a plastic toy like depicted in the question.